# Matlab merge matrices to cell

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

In Matlab I got three matrices (consisting of vectors) `x, y, z` of size `3xn` each.

I want to merge them to a cell with `n` entries, each a `3x3` matrix:

```
for i=1:n
    C{i} = [x(:,i), y(:,i), z(:,i)];
end
```

Is there a faster way than using this for loop, because that takes ages?

I already found functions like `mat2cell` and `cellfun`, but they all don't really do what I need, do they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
t = reshape([x; y; z], [3 3*n]); %//reshape your vectors into a matrix that could be use nicely with mat2cell
C = mat2cell(t, 3, 3*ones(1,n));
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless the code you are calling demands it, use a 3D array instead.  It comes with much less overhead.

```
C = zeros(3, 3, n);
for ii = 1:n
    C(:, :, ii) = [x(:,ii) y(:,ii) z(:,ii)];
end
```

In this form, you can vectorize it instead, using `reshape`:

```
C = reshape([x; y; z], [3 3 n]);
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, your code works perfectly fine as it needs to. As i requested to store it in cells I accepted Lincolns answer. For everyone else who does not have the need to store it in cells and is fine with 3d arrays, this works, too!

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-allocate the memory the improve performance:

```
C = cell(n, 1);
```